# sticky post in custom loop

Tags: loop, sticky-post

I have a problem with showing sticky posts in a custom loop. This is the code I'm using to for the custom loop:

```
<?php
    $post_from_cat_a = new WP_Query(array( 
    'category_name' => 'events',  //Get posts from category a
    'posts_per_page'=> 2 //Limit it to the latest one
    ));

    if( $post_from_cat_a->have_posts() ){
        while( $post_from_cat_a->have_posts() ): $post_from_cat_a->the_post(); //Display output here for post from category a
    $category = get_the_category(); 
    if($category[0]){
    echo '<div class="cat-events"><a href="'.get_category_link($category[0]->term_id ).'">'.$category[0]->cat_name.'</a></div>';
    }     
    get_template_part( 'content', 'events' ); 
    endwhile;
    }
?>
```

I can't figure it out why it doesn't work.

**Later edit:** this is my entire [homepage.php](http://pastebin.com/BVxmgkGJ) where the problem occurs and this is the [content-events.php](http://pastebin.com/y3FfUTBj) file used for each post in the events category.

**Second edit:** If I include `'post__in'  => get_option('sticky_posts')` in the `wp_query` array the sticky post is shown but it doesn't list the next post in the category. Only the sticky posts appears on the page, it's kind of ignoring the `'posts_per_page'=> 2` argument.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Do you have sticky posts enabled in the theme?

Comment: I'm using twentyeleven so yes they are enabled.

Comment: In what way is it not working? Do you get any output. Do you get any errors with WP_Debug on?

Comment: The post that is set as sticky in dashboard doesn't *stick* on the first page, it's getting replaced by the latest normal post.

Answer (score 1):

if you use `'post__in' => get_option('sticky_posts')` then you are only filtering on posts that are sticky.

As mrwweb said you need to look at your query. Then think of the 'loop' you want.

Do you want to show all posts in a specific query or all posts that are sticky in all categories?

1. You might need to do 2 queries or a customer database query to select the posts you want.
2. You are better off adding a tag or custom meta data to a post as you can't create a loop for sticky posts in a specific category.

Comment: I want to show the latest 2 posts from category 'events' and if one post from that category is sticky, I want it to be shown first. I don't get it why is this so hard to accomplish on wordpress...

Comment: You should use a Tag or Custom Meta Data to create a custom sticky post. Fetch Sticky posts by Category is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

### Some background

You're trying to use `query_posts` AND `WP_Query` at the same time. You only use one at a time and they're used in different ways. You'll need to review the [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and [query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) pages on the Codex and then also read these two WPSE threads:

- [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)
- [When to use WP_query(), query_posts() and pre_get_posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts)

Now, you'll see that on the WP_Query page that [sticky posts are enabled by default](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Sticky_Post_Parameters), so this really should cause you any problems. The `query_posts` line you have is straight off the Codex and with this description:

> Display just the first sticky post:

### Fixing issue

Your WP_Query stuff looks ok, so I suspect the problem is somewhere in your loop or with the content itself.

1. Remove the query_posts stuff that you don't need.
2. Double check that there is a post in the category you want that is sticky.

   - Do a `var_dump()` of `get_option( 'sticky_posts' )` and confirm that the ID of the page you want is there.
3. Try adding `'ignore_sticky_posts' => 0` to your `WP_Query` $args.
4. Make sure you haven't hardcoded a different loop on `content-home.php`. It's possible that you're outputting a different loop on that page.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanations! I removed the query_posts, did a var_dump() and got a valid output. I've also added the 'ignore_sticky_posts' argument but it's still not working. I've even removed the get_template part and tried it with the_title() and the_content() but it was the same output. I've also included in the main post two pastebin links to the homepage.php and content-events.php.

Comment: Looking at your home.php, I see that you keep saving new WP_Query instances to `$post_from_cat_a`. I don't know if that's causing the problem, but you might be running into some weird stuff there. Save each new instance of the WP_Query class to a new variable and see if that resolves it.

Comment: I've changed them to a,b,c but it's the same. Could it be something wrong with the whole wp setup? I'll have to try the same code on a different machine.

Comment: If I include `'post__in'  => get_option('sticky_posts')` in the wp_query array the sticky post is shown but it doesn't list the next post in the category. Only the sticky posts appears on the page.